# Getting the button text of WPF application from another application

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Is it possible to get the text of a button , that has been clicked in a WPF application from another c# application.... Tried **SendMessage** with the button handle , but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

[UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do what you want.  WPF controls don't have HWNDs, so SendMessage won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You dont provide much info but I will try to provide some possible solutions.
I assume by SendMessage you mean this:
[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You basically want that a c# application be able to get internal state information from a wpf application.
Or, in other words, 2 c# apps need to communicate data. Well, try this:

[InterProcess Communication](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication)

Otherwise try reflection. Reflect the wpf app into your c# app and try to get the button text value, if that value is known at compile time. But I wouldnt use reflection for just sharing a text value.